# how to remove underline of outlinedtextfield compose when its focused?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

[image]

When i try to enter some inputs to text field, it draws underline, how to remove this underline without change any color of outlinedtextfield.

```
        OutlinedTextField(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(16.dp),value = password,
        onValueChange = {
        password = it},
        leadingIcon = { Icon(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_baseline_vpn_key_24), contentDescription =  "icon-content")},
        trailingIcon = { IconButton(onClick = { passwordVisibility = !passwordVisibility }) {
            Icon(painter = icon, contentDescription = "show-password")
        }},
        placeholder = { Text(text = "Password",
        color = Color.LightGray)},
        label = { BasicText(text = "Password")},
        visualTransformation = if(passwordVisibility) VisualTransformation.None else PasswordVisualTransformation()
    )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should specify the `keyboardType` as `Password` to get rid of the text underline. You can do that by using `KeyboardOptions`:

```kotlin
OutlinedTextField(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(16.dp),
    value = password,
    onValueChange = { password = it },
    leadingIcon = {
        Icon(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_baseline_vpn_key_24),
            contentDescription = "icon-content"
        )
    },
    trailingIcon = {
        IconButton(onClick = { passwordVisibility = !passwordVisibility }) {
            Icon(painter = icon, contentDescription = "show-password")
        }
    },
    placeholder = {
        Text(
            text = "Password",
            color = Color.LightGray
        )
    },
    label = { BasicText(text = "Password") },
    visualTransformation = if (passwordVisibility) VisualTransformation.None else PasswordVisualTransformation(),
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
        keyboardType = KeyboardType.Password // HERE
    ),
)
```

This is the crucial change:

```kotlin
keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
    keyboardType = KeyboardType.Password
)
```

Comment: @EKREM YİĞİT has my answer solved Your question? :)

Answer (score 1):

The underline text is not related to color of `OutlinedTextField`.

[image]

It is related to the `keyboardType` applied. The default value is `KeyboardType.Text`.
Just add in your in `OutlinedTextField`:

```
keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Password)
```

[image]